# how use entity key (or another object) for javascript call from html

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, entity

How can I create a button that in his `onClick` event calls a function with an object? An entity key in my special case?

I populate a table of all objects in my database and want to add a delete button... The delete function needs the key, but I can't get this to work

something like the following does not work:

```
htmlString += "<td class='devicenameCol'><input id=\"deleteQuestion\" type=\"button\" value=\"löschen\" onclick=\"deleteQuestion(" + item.key + ");\"/></td>";
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing the key object itself directly as a parameter in your example. The key should be made urlsafe when using it as a parameter on your webpage: `key_safe = item.key.urlsafe()`. When reading back the key, you can then do: `key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key_safe)`.

Comment: actually, I now changed my "id" from Key to Long... But that looks exactly like what I was looking for... I will have a look at that tonight... thanks

Comment: can you tell me how I can get the urlsafe methods to work? The chrome debugger, I get the exception, that there is no urlsafe function... can I do that somehow in javascript? Or do i have to do all this in java and add the urlsafe data to my objects?

Comment: Since you did not specify that it was Java, my answer is based on the Python SDK. However, to answer your question: Yes, the urlsafe method needs to be run on the server for the instance of the key. It seems that the Java equivalent for `key.urlsafe()` is `KeyFactory.keyToString()` and `KeyFactory.stringToKey()` which are "web-safe". Here is [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Generating_Keys).

Comment: one quesiton remains: is there a simple possibility to call a function of the object in javascript? I just see the following solution: in my java code, when I generate a question, I also set the `keyString` variable... and read this variable in javascript... But I would prefer to add a method `getKeyAsString()` and call that from javascript... That's not possible, is it?

Comment: No, it is not possible and it would kind of defeat the purpose of having an urlsafe key in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I use this HTML / Jinja code in a table to create buttons in a table row:

```
<td class="center"><input class="button" type="submit" name="eid={{ rows.eid }}" value="{{ rows.caption }}"></td>
```

where :

- rows.eid contains the entity id
- rows.caption contains the button text

And I use "eid=" as a token to find the button (token) in the request data.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to go about this. If you are using the `onclick`attribute, you can call the method with a parameter like so:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(value)" />
```

Depending on how you are populating the list, this might be simple. For instance if you are using ASP.NET MVC you could do the following

```
@foreach(var entity in myEntitireDatabase)
{
    <button onclick="myFunction(@entity.Key)" />
}
```

However if you are populating the table using JavaScript, you might instead want to bind the key to a attribute, and read it from the element. For instance you could add a data-key attribute like so:

```
<button data-key="value" />
```

and the in JavaScript attach a handler for each button

```
button.addEventListener("click", myHandler)
```

and in the myHandler function, the `this` pointer is set to the element, so you could simply read the data-key attribute:

```
function myHandler(){
    var key = this.getAttribute("data-key");
    //Code to perform delete
}
```

Comment: I tried things like that, the problem is, I need something like serialisation... because in the html part, there will every object be converted to "Object object" and that's my problem...

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. That is probably because your `item.key` isn't a primitive value, but an object. Whenever you do object.toString() you get that "[Object object]" result. You should debug the script and see what value `item.key` actually holds!